# How to create transparent activity in android with transparent color

Tags: android

First sorry for my bad English ,I create one activity but how to create that activity into transparent activity with transparent background color like below image any one tell me how to create that type activity
[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is it necessary to use a second Activity? It will be a lot easier to display a semi-transparent `View` over your Activity.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create Transparent Activity in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176922/how-to-create-transparent-activity-in-android)

Comment: i already triend that one but i am getting another activty but backgrount not visible it show activity name@MidhunMP

Answer (score 1):

You can use this, this is a semi transparent color

```
android:background="#33BBFFFF"
```

For more:

http://www.coderzheaven.com/2011/07/20/how-to-create-a-transparent-activity-in-android/

http://www.prandroid.com/2014/07/how-to-create-transparent-activity-in.html

Answer (score 0):

You can set default *translucent theme* to your activity..

Or you can use *fake background* which looks like the screenshot you showed and set it to your login activity background.

I prefer the second approach this because you are going to refresh the background activity once the user logins. Also the whole experience will be faster since you don't have to wait for your background activity to load.